# 2Checkout Payment Extension Magento Error "'href' of undefined" prototype.js:612:64)

Tags: javascript, magento, paypal, prototype, 2checkout

I try to use the [2Checkout Payment Extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/2checkout-payment-extension.html) Magento I got the error to process Payment the console print like this. Anyone knows the issue.

```
prototype.js:828 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:64), <anonymous>:4:55)
at https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:64
at https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:865:29
at https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:825:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at Array.each (https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:824:12)
at Array.collect (https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:864:10)
at String.evalScripts (https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:34)
at Function.<anonymous> (https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:391:23)
at https://example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:416:23
(anonymous) @   VM297:4
(anonymous) @   prototype.js:612
(anonymous) @   prototype.js:865
(anonymous) @   prototype.js:825
each    @   prototype.js:824
collect @   prototype.js:864
evalScripts @   prototype.js:612
(anonymous) @   prototype.js:391
(anonymous) @   prototype.js:416
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed that error. I changed the code on observer.php 
It's located in /app/code/local/Craig/Tco/Model / observer.php

under  `if (Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/tco/inline')`

```
if ($$("a.top-link-cart")) { //old observer.php line 70
```

I changed this to

```
if ($$("a.top-link-cart").length) {
```

and also samething in else

```
if ($$("a.top-link-cart")) {
```

to

```
if ($$("a.top-link-cart").length) {
```

You can find more about this error on [2Checkout-Magento-Error](https://www.mazzitorch.com/2017/06/19/2checkout-payment-extension-magento-error-href-undefined-prototype/)